# Logstash JDBC input plugin execution failed with error : Expected one of #, {, } at line 9, column 60

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Am inserting oracle table information in elasticsearch via logstash configuration file, while executing the logstash config file and getting the below error message.

```
Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 8, column 84 (byte 334)
```

Please find my logstash configuration for JDBC input plugin

```
  input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\1SearchEngine\data\ojdbc8.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
    jdbc_user => "vb"
    jdbc_password => "1234567"
    statement => "select vp.id, LISTAGG(vp.code,',')within GROUP(order by vp.code)"CODE", LISTAGG(vbl.product_id,',')within GROUP(order by vbl.product_id)"PRODUCT_ID",LISTAGG(vbl.type,',')within GROUP(order by vbl.type)"TYPE" from product vp,PRODUCT_LINK vbl where vp.id = vbl.product_id group by id,vbl.product_id,vbl.type"
 }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "replacement"
  }
}
```

Please find the below error logs from logstash

```
[2018-06-14T15:42:07,683][ERROR][logstash.agent] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 8, column 84 (byte 334) after \tinput {\n\t  jdbc {\n\t\tjdbc_driver_library => \"D:\\1SearchEngine\\data\\ojdbc8.jar\"\n\t\tjdbc_driver_class => \"Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver\"\n\t\tjdbc_connection_string => \"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE\"\n\t\tjdbc_user => \"vb\"\n\t\tjdbc_password => \"1234567\"\n\t\tstatement => \"select vp.id, LISTSTAGG(vp.code,',')within GROUP(order by vp.code)\"", :backtrace=>["D:/1SearchEngine/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_imperative'",
```

Am using logstash 6.2.4 version

I gave the `SELECT` statment in single line, then also am getting the same error.

`statement => "select vp.id, LISTAGG(vp.code,',')within GROUP (order by vp.code)"CODE",LISTAGG(vbl.product_id,' , ')within GROUP(order by  vbl.product_id) "PRODUCT_ID",LISTAGG(vbl.type,' , ')within GROUP(order by vbl.type)"TYPE" from product vp,PRODUCT_LINK vbl where vp.id = vbl.product_id group by id,vbl.product_id,vbl.type"`

Comment: You need to remove the newlines in your SELECT statement

Comment: @Val i removed all the new lines in my `SELECT` statement then also am getting the same error.

Comment: Exact same one?

Comment: yes exact same one., but line # is different., because i removed newlines

Comment: but this query is tested from Oracle DB. and its working fine

Comment: Please update your question accordingly with new config and error

Comment: Question has been updated with new config and error

Comment: Can you try to escape the backslashes `D:\\1SearchEngine\\data\\ojdbc8.jar` or use forward slashes `D:/1SearchEngine/data/ojdbc8.jar`?

Comment: This error because of am using double quotes `""` in between the query now i added escape sequence `\"` and it started executing. but now am getting another error `Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::JavaSql::SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` but it is there in the query

Comment: `from` needs to be uppercased to `FROM` maybe ?

Comment: Still same error,

Comment: I would try a much simpler query first and then adding one element after another to see when it breaks

Comment: I ran with simple query earlier, but this time am having `from` after `\"TYPE\" from product` so this might causing this issue. not sure...

Comment: Try this query, remember to surround query with single quotation marks instead of double: `'select vp.id, LISTSTAGG(vp.code,",")within GROUP(order by vp.code)"CODE", LISTAGG(vbl.product_id,",")within GROUP(order by vbl.product_id)"PRODUCT_ID",LISTAGG(vbl.type,",")within GROUP(order by vbl.type)"TYPE" from product vp,PRODUCT_LINK vbl where vp.id = vbl.product_id group by id,vbl.product_id,vbl.type'`

Comment: @MichaelDz - Still getting the same error., if i surround the query with single quotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

You need to escape double quotes inside double quotes. "SELECT .. \"CODE\" ..."

And for that to work, you need to `setconfig.support_escapes: true` in your `logstash.yml` . (From [logstash docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html#_escape_sequences))

### Solution 2

Use `statement_filepath` to read statement from an external file. In this external file you do not need the enclosing quotasion marks around the query.([See link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_configuring_sql_statement))